# Change LCD information from PIC using push buttons

Tags: microcontroller, pic, lcd, pic-ccs

I can connect my PIC18F4620 to an LCD and I can display my sensor information with no problems.

Now I came into an issue, I have 3 sensors - 2 digital and 1 analog - I can perform the readings, but I can't show their results in the LCD - since it is a 16x2 - I was wondering If I can use push buttons to swipe the sensor's information in the LCD, I could do that but since my sensors have a `delay_ms(5000)` whatever I do in this 5 seconds range does not happen anything - it makes sense since it is a delay - I thought about interrupts, but I came with the very same doubt, how can I swipe the LCD screen to show another sensor information even if I have this delay?

Are there any other solutions I could use here?

I forgot to mention, I am using PIC CCS as the compiler.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're asking.  I *think* you may have your code as one big blob, instead of a sensor-reading section, an LCD-managing section, and a button-managing section.  I dread reading huge listings -- but can you *edit your question* to include your code?  Or better yet, try to reduce what you're doing to ten lines of pseudo-code and include that.

Comment: I am not a fan of the CCS compiler. You may find the Microchip XC8 code of interest [PIC18F4620 LCD and Ultrasonic range finder](https://github.com/dsoze1138/18F4620_LCD) MPLABX project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since my sensors have a delay_ms(5000) whatever I do in this 5 seconds
> range does not happen anything

Imagine *you* are the MCU, and you are given the task of reading a sensor every 5 seconds *and* changing the display if you see a button pressed. What do you do? That's right, you check the buttons *while* waiting for the next sensor read! In other words, you [multitask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking).

So instead of doing `delay_ms(5000)`, do `delay_ms(50)` and check for a button press, 100 times. This will automatically give you a 50 ms button [debounce](https://embedds.com/software-debouncing-of-buttons/) time, while making the response to button presses fast enough that the user doesn't notice.

This 'cooperative' multitasking produces variations in the total delay time depending on what is done after detecting a button press. If this is a problem then you can either reduce the delay count to compensate for the extra time taken, or run a hardware timer and read the sensor whenever the time has advanced by 5 seconds or more.

> I thought about interrupts, but I came with the very same doubt, how
> can I swipe the LCD screen to show another sensor information even if
> I have this delay?

If you use interrupts to detect button presses then they will 'cut in' during the delay and do their thing, then it will continue afterwards. However the delay will be stretched out by the time it took to respond to the button press. If you want a more accurate delay time then you might be able run a hardware timer which interrupts after 5 seconds and reads the sensor.

When using interrupts you must remember that an interrupt can occur *at any time* while your main program is running, including half way through displaying a reading. Therefore you should ensure that any variables updated by the interrupt code are 'volatile' so the main code knows they may change at any time, and 'atomic' so they don't change while it is reading them.

Comment: So I am able to execute the readings and calculations on the timer and the main loop just reads the global var and displays in the LCD including swiping right?

Comment: Yes, if you update the global variable in a timer ISR, the main loop code can simply read it (provided it is defined as Volatile to prevent caching the old value). However to make sure that a 16 bit or larger variable (which spans multiple memory locations) doesn't get partially changed _while_ reading it you should disable interrupts beforehand and re-enable them afterwards.

Comment: Got your point, but if I try to process information from sensor reading and result from the calculation, is there any performance issue if I do it in the Timer ISR?

Comment: There is a performance issue if the ISR code takes so long that it impinges on other functions, or if interrupts are missed (unlikely when the ISR only fires once every 5 seconds). Other than that the code should take the same amount of time to execute no matter where you put it. However when put in the ISR it may increase the 'latency' (response time) of other code, so it is _generally_ recommended to keep the ISR code short and do post-processing in the main code.